# How do I determine if a user is traveling along a specified route and in which direction?

Tags: geolocation, gps, routes, map-directions

Assume I have established a navigation route on a service like google maps. How do I determine if a user is traveling along that route and in which direction? Sort of like a GPS device knows if you are following the specified route or not, but also with heading info.

I'm a python hacker, but examples or resources in any language would be fine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to log a users current geolocation and the timestamp of that entry  intermittently, say every ten seconds or so.

At that point you would then have the information you need to calculate and get the final data that you need.

A good place to start is the calculating bearing section in [Calculate distance, bearing and more between Latitude/Longitude points.](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)